# Orgmode Agenda custom command is not working and shows scheduled items

Tags: emacs, org-mode

So to the point: I have made a custom visualization command for agenda using org-agenda-skip-function, so that it displays the agenda plus the unscheduled TODOs. However, I noticed that it displays the SCHEDULED todos. Not sure what is wrong. I noticed that when the entry looks like

- TITLE text

  SCHEDULED: <2018-11-18 Sun>

It does not appear. But when there is more text between the headline and  time stamps it doesn't show:

- TITLE text

More text

SCHEDULED: <2018-11-18 Sun>

This is the code I use:

```
    (setq org-agenda-custom-commands
            '(("n" "Agenda and unscheduled TODOs"
               ((agenda "" nil)
                  (alltodo ""
                  ((org-agenda-overriding-header "UNSCHEDULED TODO     entries")
                  (org-agenda-skip-function 
                  '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'scheduled 'deadline)
    )))))))
```

Thank you!
Emma

Comment: In version 9.x, the scheduling information *has* to follow the headline: you cannot have it on the same line. You might want to run the function `org-lint` on your file and see what it complains about.

Comment: BTW, your description of the problem does not make sense: When the entry looks like the first bullet "it does not appear"; when there is more text, "it doesn't show". What's the difference between the two? If there is something wrong, don't reply in a comment: just edit your question.

Comment: Thanks Nick. And sorry, there was a problem in the visualization. There should have been a new line between timestamp and heading. Anyway, now I learned that SCHEDULED: must be right below heading so it appears in agenda as a scheduled item. If there is text in between, it won't work.

Comment: That's correct. As mentioned, `org-lint` will flag problems like that.